# Javascript Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

When I run the code below, Safari's debug console tells me:

> TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById("txtHint")' [null] is not an object.

It seems to be throwing the error at this line:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

#### Code

```
 function showItem(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.responseText!='')
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getitem.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I am unsure of why this eror is thrown. There is absolutely a DIV with an ID of "txtHint" and yet safari cannot seem to run this code correctly. I guess my question is, what is wrong with this block of code.

Comment: What's the question here? Sounds like there's no element with that `ID`.

Comment: What does `console.log(document.getElementById('txtHint').length);` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not a duplicate question? Anyway, try throwing the script before the end body tag or invoking the function after dom ready / window load.

Comment: Right, window.onload or a DOM ready function. I would personally convert your code to jQuery.

Comment: I saw that in the last answer you gave me however I am so new to this I was a little overwhelmed. What are the advantages of going to jquery with this code?

Comment: jQuery abstracts away browsers differences, so you don't need to do things like: `if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for new browsers`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a syntax issue, it tells you that `document.getElementById("txtHint")` returned `null` (i.e. there was no element with that id), which means the result (`null`) is not an object, which means you can't call `.innerHTML` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree with  Ian Henry. From the error message, I guess that there is no element whose id is "txtHint" in the document .